# Trash files in the safe mode?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, safe-mode

I would like to ask you, do the trash files gets deleted from the safe mode if I put them in the trash in the safe mode (but do not empty the trash) and empty the trash in the normal mode?

Regards,
Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally yes.

The safe-mode is only blocking certain features of Mac at the boot time.
See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

> It loads only required kernel extensions (some of the items in
>   /System/Library/Extensions).
>
> It disables all fonts other than those in /System/Library/Fonts (Mac
>   OS X v10.4 or later).
>
> It moves to the Trash all font caches normally
>   stored in /Library/Caches/com.apple.ATS/(uid)/ , where (uid) is a user
>   ID number such as 501 (Mac OS X v10.4 or later). It disables all
>   startup items and login items (Mac OS X v10.4 or later).

Eg if you have a problem with a font, a corrupt driver/kernel, ... it's possible you wont be able to use your Mac, since the Mac can crash at boot etc, booting in Safe-mode is a chance to solve those problems.